# Google Cloud Storage - Bucket permission within application

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am developing a web application using GAE Java and using Google Cloud Storage to store images. The requirements are:

1. Facebook authentication. When a user is authenticated I want his profile picture to be uploaded to GCS.
2. The bucket where I store such images should obviously not allow full user access, but just read-access

I managed to get FB profile picture using Spring Social and upload to GCS but only if I set all users to owners or writers for that bucket. 
How can I only give write access within the application to upload images, but keep bucket ACL to READ_ONLY for all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [signed URLs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs). Rather than granting anonymous users permission to write to the bucket, instead give them a signed URL that allows them to write one specific object to the bucket.

Comment: signed urls can be used for some time before they expire. What I want to do is to set bucket to read only and do some kind of authorization within my request handler.

Comment: You could have your handler return a signed URL upon request to your app. Alternately, profile pictures are pretty small. You could always have users upload images directly to your handler and let your handler store the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix that. I just copied the application Service Account Name in App Engine Console under Application Settings, and added it to bucket (bucket permissions) as a new "owner" user. All other users are just "read-only"